# .NET Core 1.1.1 Project Reference not working

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-code, .net-core

So I just changed my.NET core version to the most recent one and went from project.json -> .csproject.

Now I've problems with referencing other parts of my project. I migrated a .csproj file and it gave me this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Model\Model.csproj"></ProjectReference
</ItemGroup>
```

But when I try to access classes from the referenced packages, I can't import the project, it doesn't find the reference.

The thing is when I do "dotnet build", it builds both packages, so it actually finds it. I just can't use classes from the other project.

Any help?

Comment: Curious if you tried restarting VS after clearing temp files/.vs directory/etc?

Comment: I noticed in VS2017 that IntelliSense does not appear to correctly identify a project reference.  Red squiggles galore but builds okay.  This still works very poorly in general, .NETCore is not done by a long shot.

Comment: @Matt Thomas no I didn't try that. I'll do it.

Comment: @HansPassant I ended up uninstalling .NET Core 1.1.1 and went back to an older version where project.json works.